# Force mysql varchar field to upper using select in update clause

Tags: mysql

Trying to update a table so that a field has it's contents changed to UPPERCASE.

```
UPDATE `schools` SET `postcode` = 
UPPER(
(SELECT `postcode` FROM `schools` WHERE 1)
)
```

Tried this

```
UPDATE `schools` SET `postcode` = 
UPPER( 
SELECT `postcode` FROM  (SELECT * FROM `schools`) AS x WHERE `postcode`!=''
) WHERE 1
```

I know it's possible but can't wrang that syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE `schools` 
SET `postcode` =UPPER(`postcode`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this

```
UPDATE schools SET postcode =UPPER(SELECT `postcode` FROM `schools` WHERE ur_column = values)
```